# How to change the BaudRate of SIM 7600EI while connecting with arduino UNO?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-c++, baud-rate

I am working on an Arduino UNO based project that requires the SIM 7600EI module, but the problem is that the baud rate I want to work with is different than the baud rate of SIM 7600EI.

So how can I change the baud rate of SIM 7600EI.

I am using Arduino IDE for the coding part.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to connect to the module using Serial interface other than the one used for the PC, depending on your board that would be either a second built-in interface like Serial1 or library supported interface like SoftSerial.

> Serial - Arduino to PC
>
> Serial1 - Arduino to SIM7600 module

At that point you should be able to negotiate with the module using the default baud rate set by the manufacturer.

Look for a simple serial interface echo sketch and use it to operate and query the module.

If you wish to change the serial speed you can send an AT command with desired value, check out AT+IPR in the datasheet.